# How to convert a column from feet and inches (X'X) to meters?

Tags: r, units-of-measurement

I am new to R. I have a column of heights formatted as X'X (feet and inches). I want to convert it to meters. Does anyone have any ideas?

Data:

> Height
>     4'1  6'7  6'8  5'11 5'9  6'5  4'5  6'1  4'4  4'5  6'11 6'8 
>     6'8  4'2  6'11 6'11 4'8  6'11 6'1  4'9  5'9  4'8  6'11 6'7 
>     5'8  4'10 5'1  6'3  5'3  6'6  4'9  5'5  4'1  4'7  4'4  4'4

Thank you.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please attach some example data. Is it a homework (or something like that)?

Comment: this question had been asked severally, refer to one of the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214781/converting-units-in-r

Comment: @linkonabe, none of those answers addresses parsing the string for feet and inch components. (I'm not arguing this is not a dupe, just that those answers are just for already-`numeric` unit conversions.)

Comment: @oskar homework. I attached the data. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert feet to cm in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052801/how-to-convert-feet-to-cm-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick function:

```r
ft2m <- function(s) {
  # add inches if missing or no-quotes; adding extraneous leading zeroes is okay
  s1 <- gsub("'([0-9.]*)$", "'0\\1\"", s)
  s2 <- gsub("^([0-9.]+)\"?$", "0'\\1\"", s1)
  gre <- gregexpr("([0-9.]+)(?=')", s2, perl = TRUE)
  feet <- as.numeric(regmatches(s2, gre))
  gre <- gregexpr("(?<=')([0-9.]+)(?=\")", s2, perl = TRUE)
  inch <- as.numeric(regmatches(s2, gre))
  0.3048 * (feet + inch/12)
}
```

Demo:

```r
vec <- c("5'10", "3'10\"", "0'9.3\"", "2'", "2'0", "2'0\"", "10\"")
ft2m(vec)
# [1] 1.77800 1.16840 0.23622 0.60960 0.60960 0.60960 0.25400
```

Explanation:

If you `debug(ft2m)` and look at the values of each vector post-`s2`, you'll see that the `gsub`s are making sure we have well-formatted strings.

```r
cbind(s, s1, s2)
#      s         s1        s2       
# [1,] "5'10"    "5'010\"" "5'010\""
# [2,] "3'10\""  "3'10\""  "3'10\"" 
# [3,] "0'9.3\"" "0'9.3\"" "0'9.3\""
# [4,] "2'"      "2'0\""   "2'0\""  
# [5,] "2'0"     "2'00\""  "2'00\"" 
# [6,] "2'0\""   "2'0\""   "2'0\""  
# [7,] "10\""    "10\""    "0'10\""
```

I'm "catching" strings that are feet only, inches only, or inches without `"`. It does not catch non-sensical issues such as more than 12 inches. It will also allow decimal feet *and* inches (decimal or otherwise), which though obscure are still legal if we define this as "some number, a `'`, another number, and a `"`".